# Como realizar combinaciones posibles dada una longitud y los numeros(bits) dados

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico

**Tengo este problema:** Dado dos número entero N y H, escriba un método de que imprima todas las combinaciones posibles de cadenas de bits de longitud N que tienen exactamente H bits activados.
Ejemplo de entrada: N = 4, H = 2
Ejemplo de salida: 0011 0101 0110 1001 1010 1100
Ejemplo de entrada: N = 3, H = 1
Ejemplo de salida: 100 010 001
he hecho apenas este algoritmo:

```
int i=0;
do{
    while(i<sigue){
        if(h==1){
            ma[un][i] = '1';
            ++un;i++;
        }

    }
    --nums;
}while(nums > 0);
```

pero solo logro me funciona con un bit activado sin importar la longitud(como muestra la imagen), necesito una mano para agregar los otros bits.
[image: IDE codeBlocks c++]

No importa el lenguaje de programación.

Comment: Te han faltado una par de etiquetas de lenguajes, pero creo que los *grandes* están todos ... ¿ Conoces la etiqueta [lenguaje-agnóstico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lenguaje-agn%c3%b3stico) ?

Comment: no, en serio te llamaron la atención las etiquetas que el problema?

Comment: Me llamó la atención lo mal formulada que está la pregunta, con semejante amalgama de etiquetas e imágenes incrustadas que no aportan nada que un buen *copy/paste* de texto no pueda proporcionar. ¿ Te has pasado por [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @LeonardJusaOckonell Las etiquetas tienen diversas funciones, una de las principales es notificar a una subcomunidad de SO que hay una pregunta que puede responder dicha comunidad, en tu caso abusar de ellas es no productivo. Te recomiendo evitar hacer ello, leer [ask] y pasar el [tour] si no lo has hecho.